# How can I use the cut command in awk?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I would like to use the ls -l file_path|cut -d ' ' -f 1 in awk script.I need the rights of a file and than use it as an index for an array.How can I do that?
For example: if the output of the command is this : -rw-rw-r-- 
Than I would like to be able to do something like this: Array[-rw-rw-r--]++
I tried to do this:

```
 awk '{ system("ls -l " FILENAME "|cut -d ' ' -f 1") }' `find $1 -type f`
```

to get the rights but it doesn't work.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, and particularly the "Getting Metadata on a File" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `ls` and parsing it's output use `stat` with `getline`:

```
awk '{cmd="stat -c %A " FILENAME; cmd | getline perm; close(cmd); arr[perm]++}'
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava and after I use this could you tell me how do I print the contents of the array at the end?

Comment: That would be: `END{ for (i in arr) print i, arr[i] }`

Comment: Thank you!It works just fine!But I would have a question.So this means that there are some commands that I can't use like cut?Or if I would like to use pipes and so one ?

Comment: You can use them actually in the same manner I've shown. Just construct your shell command and store in a variable e.g. `cmd`. Then run `cmd | getline cmdoutput`.

Comment: Okay.So if I write something like this it should work? awk '{ cmd="ls -l " FILENAME "|grep -woh "^.[rwx-]\{9\}"; cmd | getline perm; close(cmd); array[perm]++; }'

Comment: Sorry for the questions but I'm struggling to understand

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile so can't read all comments properly but hrs it should work.

Comment: @ReggieKapros you're thinking about this wrong. awk is not shell. UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools, NOT a tool to manipulate text. awk is a UNIX tool to manipulate text, NOT an environment from which to call other UNIX tools. If you try to use one to do the other's job you will get an ugly, fragile, mess. So while you physically can write code like `cmd="stat -c %A " FILENAME; cmd | getline perm; close(cmd);` you simply should not do it except in some extremely rare situations (that code, btw has 2 insidious bugs in it - it's fragile as I mentioned!).

Answer (score 2):

You would not write code like that as it's trying to use awk as a shell. It's like trying to dig a hole using a screwdriver while you're sitting in your backhoe. Instead you would write something like this with GNU tools:

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c %A | awk '{arr[$0]++}'
```

or even:

```
find "." -type f -printf '%M\n' | awk '{arr[$0]++}'
```

Thanks to [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for bug-fixes and inspiration in the comments.

Comment: If you have GNU tools (depending on GNU stat here), why not rely on GNU find and have `find` print the permissions directly using the `-printf` action?

Comment: I was just focused on showing how to not have awk call a shell tool in general since THAT seems to be her main issue, see her comment elsethread: `if I write something like this it should work? awk '{ cmd="ls -l " FILENAME "|grep -woh "^.[rwx-]\{9\}"; cmd | getline perm; close(cmd); array[perm]++; }'`.

Comment: (also, `-print | xargs` introduces a bunch of bugs; `-exec` would be showcasing better practices, or `-print0 | xargs -0` if you don't mind relying on GNU extensions).

Comment: Yes, I agree that you're trying to communicate something worthwhile, but showing a bunch of bad practices in the process can result in a counterproductive net effect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy FWIW I always find `-exec` too clunky, hard to enhance later and syntactically messy so I avoid it but feel free to edit the answer as you see fit, just keep the `| awk` at the end!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Darn it, you got my interest. OK wrt `-print | xargs introduces a bunch of bugs` - obviously I know it won't handle file names with newlines (fine for most applications) and I know it will handle the files in groups rather than individually (which again is fine for most applications) but what other pitfalls are there for an application like this?

Comment: Look at what happens with files with regular whitespace, not newlines, or with quote literals.

Comment: ...it's worth comparing the default behavior of xargs with that of `xargs -d $'\n'`, which is the behavior you might at present be assuming.

Comment: You are right, I rarely use xargs, only use it in the context of piped output from `find`, and always assumed it would use newlines as the separator by default and I've never come across the quotes issue before. Good to know! I'll update this answer use `-print0` and `xargs -0` and always use those going forward. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109381/discussion-between-ed-morton-and-charles-duffy).